# Trying to get calculator input display on screen?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the screen to display the numbers that are pressed on the calculator.

Currently, when you press the buttons on the calculator, the buttons do show up in the dev console.

```js
/* Cerating realtime clock for calculator*/
function setRealTime() {
  let refresh = 1000;
  let refreshTime = setTimeout("showTime()", refresh);
}

function showTime() {
  let times = document.querySelector(".time");

  const currentTime = new Date();

  let hour = currentTime.getHours();
  let minute = currentTime.getMinutes();

  hour = checkTime(hour);
  minute = checkTime(minute);

  times.innerHTML = `${hour}:${minute}`;
  setRealTime();
}

showTime();

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

/*********************
Setting up varlaibles*
**********************/

let result;
let calculation = document.querySelector(".calc");
let num1;
let num2;

/*****************************************
Function for numbers to display on screen*
******************************************/

function buttonPress(numbers) {
  result = document.querySelector(".answer").innerHTML += numbers;
  console.log(result);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto 15rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

.base {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background-color: #0c1021;
  width: 19.8rem;
  height: 40rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.time {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.icons {
  margin-left: 11.3rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
}

.icons img {
  width: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.battery {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 6%;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.hl {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.hl2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.calc-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.calc-header h2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 6rem;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -23px;
}

.screen {
  margin-left: 16rem;
  margin-top: 149px;
}

.calc {
  width: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.answer {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  margin-top: -359px;
  position: absolute;
}

.col {
  padding: 1px;
}

.col-op,
.col-op-end,
.col-num {
  width: 75.3px;
  height: 70px;
}

.col-eq-end {
  width: 155px;
  height: 68px;
}

.col-op,
.col-op-end {
  background-color: #093a52;
  color: #01a6cb;
}

.col-num {
  background-color: #0b1a2c;
  color: white;
}

#border-left {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 23px;
}

.col-eq-end {
  background-color: #01a6cb;
  color: white;
}

#border-right {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 23px 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="base">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="time"></div>
      <div class="icons">
        <img src="images/cellphone signal bars.png" alt="cellphone signal bars" />
        <img src="images/wifi bars.png" alt="wifi bars" />
        <img class="battery" src="images/battery.png" alt="battery" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dummy-nav">
      <span></span>
      <span class="hl"></span>
      <span class="hl2"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-header">
      <h2>Calculator</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="screen">
      <div class="calc"></div>
      <div class="answer"></div>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('c')">C</button>
      <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('()')">()</button>
      <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('%')">%</button>
      <button class="col-op" onclick="buttonPress('/')">/</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(1)">1</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(2)">2</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(3)">3</button>
      <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('x')">x</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(4)">4</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(5)">5</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(6)">6</button>
      <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('+')">+</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(7)">7</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(8)">8</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress(9)">9</button>
      <button class="col-op-end" onclick="buttonPress('-')">-</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <button class="col-num" id="border-left" onclick="buttonPress(0)">0</button>
      <button class="col-num" onclick="buttonPress('.')">.</button>
      <button class="col-eq-end" id="border-right" onclick="buttonPress('=')">=</button>
    </div>

  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: Your codepen appears to add the numbers correctly, but the `.answer` element is just positioned incorrectly and hidden from view behind some of the controls.

Comment: It is there... your layout just is bad.

Comment: Please do not post your code to 3rd party websites as those links can die over time, making your question here meaningless. Just include a minimal, executable version of your code right here in your question as I've done for you.